# Swift - completion handler not waiting

Tags: swift, asynchronous, alamofire

My problem is straighforward. I am fetching some data from site with TRON and I need to wait until data is successfully fetched than continue with execution. But my problem is that main thread is not waiting until completion block is completed. 
I am doing this as Unit Test, so in setUp() function

```
    Meteorites.Service.sharedInstance.fetchData(completion: { (meteorites, err) in
        if err == nil {
            self.meteorites = meteorites
        }
    })
```

than in test function I am using `meteorites` array, but I get EXC error (object is nil)

What I am doing wrong? Can someone explain me? Thanks

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping ([Meteor]?, APIError<Service.JSONError>?) -> ()) {
    print("fetching")
    let request: APIRequest<Meteorites, JSONError> = tron.request("")
    request.perform(withSuccess: { (meteorites) in
        completion(meteorites.meteorites, nil)
    }) { (err) in
        completion(nil, err)
    }
}
```

In case Meteorites class

```
class Meteorites: JSONDecodable {
    var meteorites: [Meteor]

    required init(json: JSON) throws {
        print("fetched")
        var meteorites = [Meteor]()
                    for meteorJson in json.array! {
            let dateString = meteorJson["year"]
            if dateString != JSON.null {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS" //Your date format
                dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")!
                let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString.stringValue)

                if let compareDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2011-01-01T00:00:00.000") {
                    if date! >= compareDate {
                        let meteor = Meteor()
                        meteor.date = date!
                        meteor.name = meteorJson["name"].stringValue
                        meteor.fall = meteorJson["fall"].stringValue
                        meteor.id = meteorJson["id"].intValue
                        meteor.reclong = meteorJson["reclong"].doubleValue
                        meteor.reclat = meteorJson["reclat"].doubleValue
                        meteor.mass = meteorJson["mass"].intValue
                        meteor.nametype = meteorJson["nametype"].stringValue
                        meteor.recclass = meteorJson["recclass"].stringValue
                        meteor.lastUpdate = NSDate()
                        meteorites.append(meteor)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.meteorites = meteorites


    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue in the parsing of response.

Comment: I added parsing code

Comment: add breakpoint on the last line when you are assigning meteorites to self.meteorites and see if the object is nil or not

Comment: tron.request("") also dont you need to add url here?

Comment: i am using Service class tron variable initialized as     let tron = TRON(baseURL: "http://...") so than I don't need url in request

Comment: So your issue is fixed ?